# Do all browsers support progressive image display?

Tags: html, image

Is there any list of browsers that support progressive image rendering?

Comment: Not a full list but I think this is a good article http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/progressive-jpegs-a-new-best-practice/

Answer (score 12):

A [list of browser engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support) with their JPEG compatibility is on Wikipedia; it indicates that progressive image display is supported by all standard browsers.